# Как отправить json запрос с контроллера в vue.js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, spa

Делаю spa приложения на laravel, при помощи vue.js
Пытаюсь передать данные с контроллера напрямую в представление (vue.js)

Controller:

```
 public function home()
    {
        return response()
            ->json([
                'home' => 'home'
            ], 200);
    }
```

Route api:

```
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@home');
```

app.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import App from './App.vue' //тут шапка
import router from './router' //пути

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: `<app></app>`,
    components: { App },
    router
})
```

Vue:

```
import axios from 'axios'

    export default {
        name: 'home',
        data: function() {
            return {
                home: "",
            }
        },
        created() {
                axios.get('/api/home')
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.home = response.data.home
                    });
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log(this.home);
        }
    }
```

В итоге в консоли пытаюсь вывести home - выдает пустую строку. 
А, если пытаюсь вывести  `{{ home }}`, то выскакивает ошибка:

> Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from
>   ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js): RangeError:
>   Invalid string length
>       at repeat$1 (D:\OSPanel\domains\ru\spa-laravel\node_modules\vue-template-compiler\build.js:4579:28)
>       at Object.generateCodeFrame (D:\OSPanel\domains\ru\spa-laravel\node_modules\vue-template-compiler\build.js:4561:52)

Подскажите, в чем ошибка. Делаю по примеру одного проекта, там все выводит, а у меня пустая переменная. 
Laravel 5.7 
Спасибо за помощь

Comment: А почему в then не засунуть console.log(response.data) и не посмотреть что приходит?

Comment: @yarkov_aleksei да, действительно - отображает. Но когда в представление вписываю {{ home }} - то выдает ошибку эту же

Answer (score 0):

Оптимальное решение - создать метод, для получения данных в компоненте.

```js
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: 'home',
  data: function() {
    return {
      home: "",
    }
  },
  methods: {
    load() {
      axios.get('/api/home')
        .then(r => r.data)
        .then(data => home = data.home);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.load()
  }
}
```